# How to fix the computer after forced shutdown while running wubi.exe?

Tags: wubi

How do I fix the computer after a forced shutdown while running `wubi.exe`?

I was trying to download Ubuntu via `wubi.exe`, but the screensaver came on and the mouse and the keyboard didn't work. So, I turned my laptop off without any thinking by mistake.
Then, my computer says that it can't find a operating system, so it wouldn't turn on.

How do I restore it to Windows XP?

Answer (score 0):

You need to basically **fix your windows bootloader**. You can try from [these results](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=fix+windows+bootloader&aq=f&oq=fix+windows+bootloader&aqs=chrome.0.57j0l3j62l2.3752&sugexp=chrome,mod=16&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), based on your Windows version.

You will need to basically boot into your windows installation CD and run a command `bootrec /fixmbr` in its command line.

Comment: Thank you sooo much, but can I do this instead by using a Ubuntu LIVE CD and then erasing the Ubuntu files in the documents finder inside Ubuntu("Try using Ubuntu without using any changes in the computer" mode)

Comment: @JamesLee you can investigate options [here](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=repair+windows+bootloader+from+linux&aq=2&oq=repair+windows+boo&aqs=chrome.3.57j0l3j60l2.5018&sugexp=chrome,mod=16&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) but typically it would be harder, since you are fixing something windows specific.

Comment: @JamesLee as for the files, once you fix the boot loader, you can uninstall ubuntu as if it were a normal application, or just delete the file, so there is no need to delete using Live CD

Comment: @JamesLee Or if you meant delete ubuntu using live CD to fix your booting issue, not that will not help. :(

Comment: [Boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) has a feature to ` restore a Windows-compatible MBR, ` but I am not sure how it works.